# How do I fetch the Validation errors in CakePHP 4?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have already loaded the model in the initialize method and have imported the appropriate classes. I have also created the LoginsTable Model. I went through the documentation and yet I have not found the solution.

This is the code, where I'm getting the error `$loginobj->errors()`, I'm basically trying to fetch the list or errors from the entity object.

```php
//Build entity
$loginobj = $this->Logins->newEntity($this->request->getData());
$validation_errors = $loginobj->errors();
if(!empty($validation_errors)) {
    //errors exist
    $this->Flash->set(__($validation_errors), [
        'element' => 'login_validation_errors',
        'clear' => true
    ]);
} else {
    //success
    $this->Flash->set(__('Account Created!'), [
        'element' => 'login_success',
        'clear' => true
    ]);
}
```

Comment: The `__` function translates a string. `$validation_errors` will be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

errors() is a setter, what you want is getErrors()

see: https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/class-Cake.ORM.Entity.html#_getErrors

p.s. I know this a link to 3.8 api doc, but 4.x api docs are not online for some reason, however, the syntax in 4.x for this is still the same.

p.p.s. CakePHP 4.0 API docs are now available: https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/

Comment: That solved it...Hey do you know some good resources to learn Cake PHP 4x framework in depth apart from the cookbook?

Comment: @Tuckedo see https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/awesome-cakephp